# Since I got a new hard drive, the 'tape measure' at both sides of the screen in Word documents has disappeared

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open a Word document, a 'tape measure' appears on the right and left side of the screen. Using the cursor, I can extend the space available for text down to the bottom and/or up to the top of the page. That way, I can get more text onto one page. Recently my computer needed a new hard drive and when I got it back, the 'tape measure' had disappeared. How do I get it back??

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MS Word 2007 or 2010, go to the "View" tab, and check the "ruler" checkbox.